# PNG Overlay not correct using L.CRS.EPSG3857 projection

Tags: leaflet, gis, coordinate-systems

I am using leaflet and openstreet maps.  I created a png using EPSG3857 however the image is not laying correctly on the map.

[image: Bad Overlay]

if you look at the Baja Region and Florida you will see the data on land.  The data should be over the water not the land.

```
 var map = L.map('map', { editable: true },{crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857}).setView(initialCoordinates , initialZoom),   
 tilelayer =
    L.tileLayer(url_tile,
        {
            noWrap: true,
            maxZoom: 12, minZoom: 2, attribution: 'Data \u00a9 <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"> OpenStreetMap Contributors </a> Tiles \u00a9 HOT'
        }).addTo(map);

var overlay_image = 'images/webmercator-google.png';
imageBounds = [[-90, -180], [90, 180]];
L.imageOverlay(overlay_image, imageBounds, { opacity: 0.8 }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using EPSG:3857, Leaflet clamps all latitude data to +/-85.05° (or, to be precise, +/-20037508.34 on the EPSG:3857 Y coordinate). This is done to prevent data appearing outside of the coverage area of default EPSG:3857 tiles.

To illustrate this, consider the following bit of code:

```
for (var i=83; i<90; i+=0.1) {
    L.marker([i, i]).addTo(map);
}
```

That should (naïvely) display a lot of markers in a diagonal-ish line. But when [actually doing that](https://plnkr.co/edit/UaPlOrgSaHRGL4th), the result looks like:

[image: Leaflet markers latitude-clamped]

See how the markers don't go north of the 85.01° parallel, and how that fits the limit of tiles (blue sea versus grey out-of-map background).

Remember, EPSG:3857 and any other (non-traverse, non-oblique) cylindrical projections cannot display the north/south poles because they get projected to an infinite Y coordinate.

---

OK, so what does this have to do with your problem? You're using:

```
imageBounds = [[-90, -180], [90, 180]];
```

But, since Leaflet will clamp latitudes, that's actually the same as doing:

```
imageBounds = [[-85.01, -180], [85.01, 180]];
```

Keep this in mind when using `L.ImageOverlay`s that cover areas near the poles. You probably want to recreate your image using a narrower band of latitudes.

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge.  Where did you find the max image bounds that leaflet use.  I searched and searched but couldn't find anything.  I will recreate the image using narrower values.

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/main/src/geo/projection/Projection.SphericalMercator.js#L19=